# Getting rid of extra changes in current working directory after a git add -p and commit?

Tags: git

I used the following commands:

`git add -p
(added like 80% of changes, the other 20% are useless or unwanted changes.)
git commit
git push origin (some branch name)`

I want my CWD to look like what I committed and pushed. But my CWD has 100% of changes, not just the 80% that I want. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

After you commit, you can do a `git reset --hard && git clean -f -d`

The first reset's head to the latest commit and the latter removes untracked files. Read more about it typing `git help reset` and `git help clean`